# Ubuntu with Kernel 5.11.0-46 won't load/boot

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

This morning, I updated Ubuntu to use kernel 5.11.0-46 as recommended by the software updater. However, Ubuntu won't load after the update.

I am able to get to GRUB and select 5.11.0-44 as the kernel and get into Ubuntu but I'm not sure how I can address this issue long term. I tried changing the default kernel that GRUB uses as follows:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-44-generic
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.ppfeaturemask=0xfffd7fff"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0
```

This, however, did not improve matters and it still causes the OS to not load after GRUB. I even tried to remove the `quiet splash` to see if I could get the verbose OS load to no avail.

Any ideas how to address this? I want to understand why this is happening and what I can do to help solve this issue.

**UPDATE**: Had incorrect entry in `GRUB_DEFAULT`:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-44-generic"
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash amdgpu.ppfeaturemask=0xfffd7fff"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0
```

Also, had forgotten to update GRUB after modifying the file:

```
sudo update-grub
```

I can now boot into 5.11.0-44 by default.

I’ll file a bug as recommended in the comments so this gets tracked correctly.

Comment: We'd appreciate it if you could provide a detailed answer, including all of the commands you used and the corrected `DEFAULT` entry.

Comment: @user68186 That does actually help me out. Filling a bug report may help out the community at large, as I suspect I’m not the only one with this issue. The other entries in that question are exactly what I had found to be done. Thank you for the input!

Comment: @Someone Updated question after your input. Thank you!